# Hide "null" result

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, sharepoint

I've a working searching function embedded to a HTML website to search informations on a Sharepoint site.
This is working but when I have a result without a "Description", the result show "null".
So, i want to hide this null value :) And I don't know how I can do that.

Here is my function for the search/result :

```
<script>
    function searchListener(text){
        var count = 0;
        $(".result").empty();
        var queryGet = "MY URL";
        $.ajax({ url: queryGet, method: "GET", headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" }, success: onQuerySuccess, error: onQueryError });
        function onQuerySuccess(data) {
            var results = data.d.query.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table.Rows.results;
            var title,url, index, id, desc;
            console.log(results);
            $.each(results, function () {

                $.each(this.Cells.results, function () {

                    if(this.Key == "Title"){
                        title = this.Value; 
                    }
                    if(this.Key == "Path"){
                        url = this.Value;
                    }
                    if(this.Key == "Description"){
                        desc = this.Value;
                    }
                });


                count = count +1;

                if(((url.indexOf('qt') !== -1) || (url.indexOf('news') !== -1) || (url.indexOf('tuto') !== -1) || (url.indexOf('service_data') !== -1)) && (url.indexOf('DispForm') !== -1)){
                    if(url.indexOf('qt') !== -1) index ="quicktraining";
                    if(url.indexOf('tuto') !== -1) index ="tuto";
                    if(url.indexOf('news') !== -1) index ="news";
                    if(url.indexOf('service_data') !== -1) index ="service";

                    id = url.split('ID=')[1];

                    $(".result").append("<div class='bullet'><a class='searchlink' id='"+ id +" "+ index + "' href='#'><h2>" + title +"</h2></a><h4 id='desc'>" + desc + "</h4></div>");
        }


    });

        }
        function onQueryError(error) {
            if($(".form-control").val().length != 0){
                $(".result").append("<h5>No results found</h5>");
                $(".result").show();
            }else{
                $(".result").hide();
            }

        }

    }

</script>
```

AN idea ?
Many thanks!

Comment: I guess you just check for the value of `desc` before you continue appending to the DOM?

Comment: `if(this.Key == "Description"){
if(this.Value !== null){
                        desc = this.Value;
} else {desc = ' '}
                    }`?

Comment: @KevinKloet same answer as Vaibhav Shimpi. Now i've no result with this conditions :(

Comment: @Kreg do you get the `"<h5>No results found</h5>"` or are all the values empty?

Comment: @Kevin all values are empty :/

Comment: @Kreg you could make `desc` an array and push the values to the array, the reason it is empty is probably because the each loop overwrites the var every time it loops thus making the var equal to the last one in the loop

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(this.Cells.results, function () {

                    if(this.Key == "Title"){
                        title = this.Value; 
                    }
                    if(this.Key == "Path"){
                        url = this.Value;
                    }
                    if(this.Key == "Description")
                    {
                      if(this.Value != " ")
                      {
                        desc = this.Value;
                      }
                      else
                      {
                        desc = "";
                      }                        

                    }
                });
```

hope this will work for you...

Comment: I've tested, but unfortunately now I have no result...
I don't understand why :(